# Word order: Neck & Back Pain VS Back & Neck Pain

Tags: word-usage, american-english

I'm working on a website and I'm trying to figure out which one is correct:

1. Neck & Back Pain

or

2. Back & Neck Pain

Comment: It isn't a question of which is correct -- both are from the point of view of English --  but what is likely to grab users' interest most.  My vote is for Back and Neck pain, because more people seem to have back pain than neck pain.  How much emphasis does your site put on the two?  I am going to Vote to Close because from an English point of view, this is a matter of opinion.

Comment: There is no single "correct" order here, or in most such cases.  It's a question of whether one order is more "idiomatic", and, lacking a decision on that basis, whether one or the other "sounds better".  In this case I don't see a strong argument on either basis.

Comment: Once again I'm seeing contributors on this site saying something is "opinion based" and not welcome on the site, while the same type of question gets taken seriously in professional scholarship on English language and linguistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct.

As to which is more *common*, [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=back%20and%20neck%20pain%2C%20neck%20and%20back%20pain&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cback%20and%20neck%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneck%20and%20back%20pain%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cback%20and%20neck%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneck%20and%20back%20pain%3B%2Cc0) suggests that *back and neck pain* has a slight lead in popularity—at least with the written form:

[image: back and neck pain]

If I look only at the [UK English corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=back%20and%20neck%20pain%2Cneck%20and%20back%20pain&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cback%20and%20neck%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneck%20and%20back%20pain%3B%2Cc0), *back and neck pain* is much more common:

[image: back and neck pain—UK]

If I look only at the [US English corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=back%20and%20neck%20pain%2Cneck%20and%20back%20pain&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cback%20and%20neck%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneck%20and%20back%20pain%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cback%20and%20neck%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneck%20and%20back%20pain%3B%2Cc0), the two are essentially identical—even though *neck and back pain* has a very slight edge:

[image: neck and back pain—US]

Finally, if I look at the [2009 US English corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=back%20and%20neck%20pain%2Cneck%20and%20back%20pain&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cback%20and%20neck%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneck%20and%20back%20pain%3B%2Cc0) (which even, I think, Google says is questionable), it indicates that the lead for *neck and back pain* has increased:

[image: neck and back pain—US (2009)]

(The data for 2009 UK English shows no difference from the normal 2000 UK English.)

---

On the other hand, it also shows that, taken singly, it's far [more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=back%20pain%2Cneck%20pain&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cback%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneck%20pain%3B%2Cc0) for *back pain* to appear in writing than it is for *neck pain*. (That link is for US English, but it applies to both US and UK and to all years.)

In short, take your pick. The combined *back and neck pain* would likely sound more normal to poeple in a global audience. But since you tagged your question with `american-english` specifically, this data is at least suggestive of the fact that *neck and back* pain is a bit more common. Still, both are easily understood—and you should simply pick whichever sounds best to you or fits in consistently with other phrasing or stylistic branding that you've used.

Comment: Thanks, I think this was very helpful. I went with the back and neck pain.

Answer (score 0):

It's a tricky question and there is actually a decent amount of research on the question of ordering in binomial compounds. Try the paper linked below as a starting point.

http://idiom.ucsd.edu/~rlevy/papers/benor-levy-2006.pdf